# Convert Video into JPEG Sprite

Tags: jquery, image, video, sprite

I know video can't be turned directly into a motion JPEG but what I'm after is for each frame in a sequence to be taken from the video and turned into a JPEG sprite either horizontal or vertical.

I'll then be using jQuery to animate the jpeg sprite into what looks like a video again.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can turn a movie into a stitched together sprite file by doing the following:

1) Use ffmpeg to turn the movie into a bunch of images (this example uses 10 fps)

```
ffmpeg -i "infile.mp4" -f image2 -vf fps=fps=10 img%03d.jpg
```

2) Then use imagemagick to stitch them together

```
files=$(ls img*.jpg | sort -t '-' -n -k 2 | tr '\n' ' ')
convert $files -append output.jpg
```

BOOM - you've got a sprite sheet.

Comment: For windows the ffmpeg command works out of the box, but I can't seem to get the imagemagick command running under windows. Anyone cares to help converting?

Comment: for windows you can do `magick convert *.jpg -append output.jpg`

Comment: `convert *.jpg -append output.jpg` works for macOS

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/download.html) to extract frames into images. The following command pulls a single frame five seconds in:

`ffmpeg -i "infile.mp4" -r 1 -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:01 -vframes 1 -f image2 -y "image.jpg"`

Comment: Legend!! This looks or rather sounds exactly what I'm after. Do you know of a screen capture tool that this would be able to read the results from as well?

Comment: Not to worry I've found a free software called camstudio that creates avi of screen. Thanks again :)